# How to check in an asp text box has @ sign

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm developing a module where I need to take input from a user one of each is users email. In order to filter out a wrong input I want to check if a corresponding `checkbox` has an `@` sign.

Does anyone knows how can I check it using `vb.net` ?

Comment: use the `String.Contains("@")` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx  on the control: `TextBox.Text.Contains("@")`

Comment: I think is better to check if is a "valid" email address like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331084/how-do-i-validate-email-address-formatting-with-the-net-framework

Answer (score 2):

Aside the main question to check if a string contains the `@` character and considering that you are getting your string from a user input, in your case I think is better to check if the user entered a **valid** mail address.

To do so there are some solutions all reported in this other SO question [How do I validate email address formatting with the .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331084/how-do-i-validate-email-address-formatting-with-the-net-framework)

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET you can use `RegularExpressionValidator` for this.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexEmailValid" runat="server" 
      ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
      ControlToValidate="tbEmail" 
      ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Format">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: It will not prevent the execution

Comment: How can I block the execution if the is triggered?